# An upgrade of a simple welder

Tags: power-supply, transformer, high-current, bridge-rectifier

I've been needing to get some welding projects done, but am reluctant to cough up $800 or more for a TIG & stick combo welder.

However, I have an old simple buzz box welder (basically an oversized transformer) I bought more than a decade ago: [image]

I've torn it down & basically this is the schematic, without the  thermal overload switch: [image]

So I was thinking, maybe I can soup up this ole welder. I thought of a novel approach. First, I needed to know if this old welder could be plugged in to 220V. So I plugged it in our dryer receptacle, which I was intending to be my power source. Turning on, the welder seemed just fine (I didn't actually do any welding as I've already cut off the cables long ago, such is my impulse to teardown many of my own tools).

Next, I would be full wave rectifying the 220V mains AC. This will create a waveform we all know somewhat looking like a sinusoidal itself. Almost a dirty sine wave, with twice the frequency, that has a DC offset:
[image]

This would then be fed to the transformer, which would rid of this apparent DC offset:
[image]

Lastly, it would be rectified (again, making it look like the frequency has quadrupled in total), because the the aluminum welding I would be doing has polarity:
[image]

[image]

Here's the schematic:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G3JGezvGJKj1dwShcNkYQzUxvAr4Oyqj/view?usp=sharing

It was a simple rig (which took me weeks to do because of issues of locations). Anyways, when the rig was almost complete, I plugged the welder to the dryer receptacle & switched it on. As soon as I did, the circuit breaker was tripped & for a split second before the trip, I swear I heard a buzz from the transformer that was a bit more audible than usual.

I could only surmise that the rig drew so much current (greater than  30A the dryer receptacle is rated for) that it was almost a short. Though how that could be is a bit of a mystery for me as the inductor that is the transformer should oppose an inrush of current.

My quick fix right now is to add a capacitor to divert this inrush of current:
[image]
The schematic: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VQW9zKP708K-WiBVNKxlhEuWuw-THUWB/view?usp=sharing

I just can't simulate it so the current on the load is 10s & 10s of amps, but I can get it to work... The quick fix of adding the (peak detector) capacitor is something I've yet to try yet. If anybody sees an issue with this, do let me know before I try it.

EDIT:
I would like users to comment on why there is such a large inrush current when the rig is turned on & is the peak detector capacitor an adequate enough fix?

Comment: Diodes 1N4148 should be a "little" low as currents ... And a 120 V transformer should not be used with 230 V ... And I am "skeptical" on the two last schematic (?).

Comment: Entry level inverter TIG welders are available for far less than 800 USD. It would be safer and more reliable than modifying your existing.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of problems with your design. As mentioned in the comments a 1N4148 is too small for the current you wish to use, and testing a 120 V transformer with 230 V was not wise (I'm surprised it didn't trip your circuit breaker).

I wish to add to that list that rectifying the input to the transformer means the transformer is fed with both an AC component and a DC component. If the transformer core does not saturate with 230 V, it surely would with the large DC component you are feeding the transformer.

Transformer core saturation leads to very large primary currents, and this is most certainly the cause of your circuit breaker tripping.

Comment: So shouldn't I be preventing these large primary currents, rather than drawing more, with having a capacitor in parallel the primary winding? Maybe a capacitor in series to the primary winding, blocking DC, would work better? https://drive.google.com/file/d/10fWS33fQuJpPglLpn27nXa97Spvi24yq/view?usp=drive_link